# Is the Countries data in Google Search Console correct? How accurate is it?

Tags: google-search-console

I've been seeing impressions coming from all over the world in Google Search Console. I see queries coming from countries that don't have a volume data in SEO tools for a particular country. So, I was wondering if GSC's data is accurate. Also, could it be possible that there could be people who might be using some kind of VPN from let's say restricted countries like China from where people are connecting to other country servers?

How does Google Search Console surmise which country the impression took place in?

Comment: This is a good question, but I'm not sure that Google has released any documentation about it.  I'm not sure how we would be able to test it from the outside.

Comment: I'd suspect the volume data from your SEO tools is less accurate. Ask them where they get their data from.